# Unable to start PSQL in DigitalOcean

Tags: database, digital-ocean, psql

I am unable to connect to PSql from my DigitalOcean server. This happened after resizing the droplet.

```
listen_addresses = '*' added to postgresql.conf
host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5 added to pg_hba.conf
```

`netstat -nlp` displays the following:

```
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6379          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1705/redis-server 1
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8080          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      23688/unicorn.conf 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1693/nginx      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1390/sshd       
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1693/nginx      
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1390/sshd       
Active UNIX domain sockets (only servers)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node   PID/Program name    Path
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     10806    1173/dbus-daemon    /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     711      1213/systemd        /run/systemd/private
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     11921    1213/systemd        /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     11924    1213/systemd        /run/snapd.socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     11925    1213/systemd        /run/snapd-snap.socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     2813     1449/acpid          /var/run/acpid.socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     9801     1/init              @/com/ubuntu/upstart
unix  2      [ ACC ]     SEQPACKET  LISTENING     427      708/systemd-udevd   /run/udev/control
```

Comment: Can you provide more info? What error you got?

Comment: I get this error when I try to connect the DB.

psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?

Comment: The PostgreSQL server is not running, so you cannot connect to it. Start it!

Comment: Tried '/etc/init.d/postgresql restart'. Result is 'postgresql: command not found'. This happened after I resized the digital ocean machine.